# The wrong site title is coming up for home page

Tags: 7

For some reason, the title of our website in browser windows and tabs is coming up as something else. We aren't even sure where this title came from, as it has nothing to do with our site.

I checked the page source to see what was showing up in the `<title>` tags, and sure enough, it's the same, incorrect title.

I tried changing the name of the site and the site's slogan, hoping that would help. I've cleared the caches. It's been going on for about 8 months, before we made some upgrades to core and modules.

[image]

[image]

Other page titles seem to be working correctly. There are no nodes with this title. We are using Drupal Commons. Drupal version 7.50.

Comment: The wrong title has been on the homepage for eight months? Is it hardcoded in metatag global config?

Comment: The value of front page global metatag title is [site:name] but is still coming up wrong even after reverting everything. On local dev, everything is the same but the title is correct or the revert worked. Why not on production?

Comment: Are you running memcache? Did you flush all the caches?

Comment: I did `drush cc all`. I'm not sure how to clear the memcache but I feel like it's  causing my log in issue as well.

Comment: Log in issues? So many problems... if nothing in the code or database mentions Back to School, I can only guess it is cached in memory - any services running on prod that you aren't running locally?

Comment: Are you out of opcache memory?

Comment: How do I check?

Comment: You can see in the php status report via drupal admin - check opcache memory used vs free. If the free value is very very small you may need to increase and reboot the server. Just a wild guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the `<title>` element is set in [`template_preprocess_html`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7.x)

```
  // Construct page title.
  if (drupal_get_title()) {
    $head_title = array(
      'title' => strip_tags(drupal_get_title()),
      'name' => check_plain(variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')),
    );
  }
  else {
    $head_title = array('name' => check_plain(variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')));
    if (variable_get('site_slogan', '')) {
      $head_title['slogan'] = filter_xss_admin(variable_get('site_slogan', ''));
    }
  }
  $variables['head_title_array'] = $head_title;
  $variables['head_title'] = implode(' | ', $head_title);
```

That is then output in your theme [`html.tpl.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21html.tpl.php/7.x)

You may have some code or configuration overriding the default title there in a module or theme.

I'd suggest searching through the codebase for the title text, or perhaps in a db dump file.

After that, you can either update it, or add some code for your own HTML `<title>` logic.

Comment: No one could have guessed this, but there was some bad code inserted into a blog post (it was supposed to be the alt-title for an image I think) and even though it was posted almost a year ago, it was causing the issue. I didn't catch it until I migrated that content over to a new website and the same thing happened.

In summary, bad code can cause all kinds of issues. I've since changed all WYSIWYG editors to allow filtered HTML only for all roles except user/1.